# Nestjs auth and user Module circular dependency

Tags: typescript, nestjs

My issue is that I need an auth module and user module each containing a service (eg. auth and user service).

First I wanted to import the user module (whcih exports the user service) into the auth module. However now the user controller should return an jwt (created by auth service) instead of the user id etc. which was returned by the user service before.

This results in a circular dependency.
(I thought all interactions with the user table should be run through the user service)

Is there a best practise to handle this?

Comment: Why don't you merge these into one module only? And one service eventually.

Comment: I wanted to separate them since CRUD operations for users and authentication are only loosely related. Would it also be possible to make a "UserServiceModule" and "AuthServiceModule" to be able to import them seperately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: use [forwardRef](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency).
Here's an extract from their discord:

[image]